# Server sent events connection closed or data not received

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to create event end-points with the ASP.net MVC 4 web-api controller. The problem is that the moment I try to flush the stream it throws an exception saying:

```
The remote host has closed the connection.
```

Or it just looks like the client-side doesn't receive anything. Even though it can flush the data written to the stream.

I first used the [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object to store the `StreamWriter` in a wrapper with the identifying `Guid`. Now I store it as key-value pair in the [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) object. I don't know if that makes it any different.

Client-side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var event = new EventSource('/back-end/events/tracklisting/866594c8-8411-11e4-9fcb-5254005dbd0a?juke=392fcbe5-8523-e4-9fcb-5254005dbd0a');
    event.onopen = function () {
        console.log('Onopen event fired!');
    };
    event.onmessage = function (e) {
        console.log('incoming data: ' + e.data);
    };
    event.onerror = function () {
        console.log('Event source error occurred!');
    };
</script>
```

ASP.Net Event end-point:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage TrackListing(HttpRequestMessage req, string token, string juke) {
    var response = req.CreateResponse();
    response.Content = new PushStreamContent((stream, content, ctx) => {
        trackListingSubscribers.TryAdd(new Guid(juke), new StreamWriter(stream));
    }, "text/event-stream");
    response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    return response;
}
```

Concurrent Stream Storage:

```
public static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, StreamWriter> trackListingSubscribers = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, StreamWriter>();
```

Dispatch event function:

```
    public static void sendTrackListingEvent(Guid juke)
    {
        foreach(var subscriber in EventsController.trackListingSubscribers.Where(kvp => kvp.Key == juke)) {
            subscriber.Value.WriteLine(string.Format("data: {1}\"refresh\": true,\"juke_id\":\"{0}\" {2} \n", subscriber.Key.ToString(), "{", "}"));
            subscriber.Value.Flush();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very simple. It was the Javascript.

```
event.onmessage = function(e) {
    //Event logic
};
```

Should not be used. You should use:

```
event.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    //Event logic
});
```